# facebook Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using facebook connect on my website, I'm authenticating using fb javascript sdk, and also using fb php sdk for getting users information, everything works fine but when the user logs out from facebook (from next tab), the php sdk throws an exception

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating access token:
>   The session is invalid because the user logged out. thrown in
>   C:\wamp\www\fbjs\base_facebook.php on line 1033

After Logout from facebook the site behaves strange, I can get user id through this code even after the fb logout

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();///get my fb id
```

but then on next line it calls the api using the facebook object then it throw the above exception.

Any idea how can I check if the is the user is still on fb or not b/c I get fbid but exception on `$facebook->api`  call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception itself is what tells you if the user is logged in.  Catch the exception, and re-run your authentication flow.

This article from the Facebook documentation might help:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: detecting the user status with the exception is not a good way, do have any other way so I can get the user is logged in or not???

Comment: when something fall inside an exception this is not good, is this what fb recommend???

Comment: According to the Facebook docs, getUser() should be returning 0 if the user isn't logged in.  You sure you've got a valid user id even after the user has logged out?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getUser/